# Formatting number (as a string) to time in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

Feel a bit silly asking this on here but I'm at a loose end with what to search to give me the answer on this one, so here is the question:

I have a number such as:

0800

Ideally I would like to format this (using PHP) into 8:00am - is this possible?

Hope you can help,

Tom

Comment: You mean you have a string "0800"? How do you know if it's am or pm? Is it in 24-hour format?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. It's a string in 24hour format so I know that it's am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can use is `date()` function and the code below:

```
date("h:ia",strtotime("0800"))
```

More info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

And also one example would be awesome: http://codepad.org/uUuoZK1A

Comment: Thank you for this, I was so close! Do you know how I would get the "am" and "pm" onto that as well

Comment: Eventually went for date("H:ia",strtotime("0800")); - thank you all

Answer (score 5):

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("Hi", "0800")->format("h:ia");
```

For more information (including info about the placeholders) see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php.

Comment: awesome solution, unfortunately I am only on 5.2.17

Comment: Do you know what's the advantage of this method over `Date()` function?

Comment: In this case there isn't much difference, but especially if you're working with timezones or time intervals the DateTime classes are a lot "cleaner" and easier to use in my opinion. Related documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 2):

This would work

```
    <?php
    $input = "0800";
    $hours = substr($input, 2);
    $mins = substr($input, -2);
    if($hours  < 12)
    {
    $output = $hours.":".$mins." am";
    }
    else
    {
    $output = ($hours-12).":".$mins." pm";
    }
    echo $output;
    ?>
```

Comment: date("H:ia",strtotime("0800")) is a much more elegant solution. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', '0800');
echo $time->format('h:ia');
```

Comment: again, unfortunately, only on 5.2.17 - Damn Media Temple!